# Удаление столбцов в DataFrame состоящих только из NaN значений

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется df c многими тысячами столбцов, которые целесообразно удалять в цикле и при условии, что они целиком пустые. 
Написал код:

```
for n in df_balance.columns:
    if df_balance[n].any() == False:
        df_balance.drop(columns=df_balance.loc[:, n], inplace=True)
```

но он выдает ошибку:

`KeyError: 'labels [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] not contained in axis'`

Подскажите, где ошибся.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение в одной строчке:

```
df_balance.dropna(axis='columns',how='all', inplace=True)
```